# Extracting data from an API in typescript vue and to a prop

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need some help guys. Anytime I've done this I've used a v-for and extracted the data manually. The problem I am facing here is that the component I am passing the data to is a custom component already written to accept the data in an `:options` prop. But all I am getting is "null" for every piece of state.

Here is the template

```html
<WDropDown label="Commissioner" :options="dropdownCommissionerValues" v-model="commissioner1"/>
```

And the `script lang="ts"`

```js
// Data Section
apiInvoker= methods; //this is coming from a service file that logs to the API
public commissioner1 = "1";
dropdownCommissionerValues= [];

mounted () {
  this.apiInvoker.viewRequestGet("resources/GetCommisionerList").then((response) => {
    if(response.data) {
      this.dropdownCommissionerValues = response.data.Table;
      console.log("My Response is", this.dropdownCommissionerValues);
    }
  });
}
```

Inspecting the Vue Dev Tool, and the console, I am connecting to the API and I am getting data in the component. See image below

[image]

But this is what I am getting in the browser See image

[image]

NOTE, If I hardcode my data in `dropdownCommissionerValues` as shown below, it get it to work. But I need it to come from the API

```js
this.dropdownCommissionerValues= [
  {
     value:"1",
     text:"Something 1"
  },
  {
     value:"2",
     text:"Something 2"
  }        
]
```

I assume somehow I have to pass CommissionerId as value and CommissionerName as text because that's how the component reads it? I just can't figure out how

Thanks in advance!

Here is the custom component

```html
    <template>
  <ValidationProvider :vid="id" :name="id" :rules="rules" v-slot="wDropDown">
    <wFormGroup :class="classObject"
                :id="groupId('lbl', id)"
                :label="label"
                :label-for="id"
                :label-sr-only="labelSrOnly">
      <template v-if="(pagePlaintext || plaintext || isPlaintext) && !dropDownBind">
        <b-form-input plaintext
                      aria-readonly="true"
                      readonly="readonly"
                      :aria-label="label"
                      :data-vv-as="label"
                      :id="id"
                      :name="name"
                      :type="type"
                      :value="refDataValue" />
      </template>
      <template v-else-if="dropDownBind">
        <div :class="divClass">
          <b-form-select class="attachedSelect"
                        :id="id"
                        :aria-label="label"
                        :aria-required="required"
                        :data-vv-as="label"
                        :data-vv-name="label"
                        :data-vv-scope="scope"
                        :class="{ 'is-invalid': wDropDown.errors.length > 0  }"
                        :disabled="disabled || arcDisabledObj"
                        :label="label"
                        :multiple="multiple"
                        :name="name"
                        :options="options"
                        :select-size="selectSize"
                        :text-field="selectText"
                        v-model="computedVal"
                        :value-field="selectValue"
                        @input="onInput">
            <template slot="first" v-if="!(multiple) && displayFirstSlot">
              <option v-if="customFirstSlotValue !== null"
                      :value="customFirstSlotValue">
                {{placeholderText}}
              </option>
              <option v-else-if="computedVal !==null && computedVal !== undefined && computedVal.length ===0"
                      computedVal>
                {{placeholderText}}
              </option>
              <option v-else :value="null">{{placeholderText}}</option>
            </template>
          </b-form-select>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <div :class="divClass">
          <b-form-select class="form-control"
                        :id="id"
                        :aria-label="label"
                        :aria-required="required"
                        :data-vv-as="label"
                        :data-vv-name="label"
                        :data-vv-scope="scope"
                        :class="{ 'is-invalid': wDropDown.errors.length > 0 }"
                        :disabled="disabled || arcDisabledObj"
                        :label="label"
                        :multiple="multiple"
                        :name="name"
                        :options="options"
                        v-model="computedVal"
                        :select-size="selectSize"
                        :text-field="selectText"
                        :value-field="selectValue"
                        @input="onInput">
            <template slot="first" v-if="!(multiple) && displayFirstSlot">
              <option v-if="customFirstSlotValue !== null"
                      :value="customFirstSlotValue">
                {{placeholderText}}
              </option>
              <option v-else-if="computedVal !==null && computedVal !== undefined && computedVal.length ===0"
                      computedVal>
                {{placeholderText}}
              </option>
              <option v-else :value="null">{{placeholderText}}</option>
            </template>
          </b-form-select>
        </div>
      </template>
      <b-form-text v-if="helpText" :id="groupId('hlp', id)">{{helpText}}</b-form-text>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="wDropDown.errors.length > 0">{{ Message }}</div>
      <!-- {{ isRequired && (!plaintext && !pagePlaintext) }} {{ isRequired }} {{ plaintext}} {{ overridePageMode }} -->
    </wFormGroup>
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
  import uuid from "uuid/v1";

  import { groupId } from "@/helpers";
  import { classObject } from "@/computed";
  import { pagePlaintext } from "@/mixins";

  /*
    [DEPRECATED]: Left in to support Organization page. Do not use otherwise.
    This should be removed in the future.
  */
  import { arcInputStateMixin } from "@/components/mixins/UI/inputStateMixin";

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        scope: uuid(),
        Message: 'This field is required.',
      };
    },
    methods: {
      groupId,
      onInput (value) {
        this.$emit("input", value);
      },
      getSelectedDataValue (options, keyValue, keyField, valueField) {
      let result = null;
      let response = null;
      console.log(options);
      console.log(keyValue);
      console.log(keyField);
      console.log(valueField);
      console.log(keyValue !== undefined && keyValue !== null);
      if(keyValue !== undefined && keyValue !== null) {
        response = options.filter(option =>  option[keyField].toString() === keyValue.toString());
      }
      console.log('wDropDown', this.id);
      console.log(response);
      if (this.isNotNullOrUndefined(response)) {
        result = response[0][valueField] || null;
      }
      return result !== null ? result : this.readOnlyValue;

    },
    },
    mixins: [arcInputStateMixin, pagePlaintext],
    model: {
      event: "input",
      prop: "value",
    },
    name: "wDropDown",
    props: {
      isRequired: Boolean,
      dropDownBind: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      disabled: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
      displayonly: {
        type: String,
      },
      helpText: {
        type: String,
      },
      id: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
      },
      inputState: {
        type: String,
      },
      label: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
      },
      labelFor: {
        type: String,
      },
      labelSrOnly: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
      maxlength: {
        type: String,
      },
      multiple: {
        type: [String, Boolean],
        default: false,
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      options: {
        default () {
          return [];
        },
        type: [Array, String],
      },
      placeholderText: {
        type: String,
        default: "- Select One -",
      },
      plaintext: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
      required: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
      selectSize: {
        type: String,
      },
      selectText: {
        type: String,
        default: "text",
      },
      selectValue: {
        type: String,
        default: "value",
      },
      type: {
        type: String,
      },
      value: {
        type: [Number, String, Array],
        default: null,
      },
      validation: {
        type: String,
      },
      customFirstSlotValue: {
        type: [String, Number],
        default: null,
      },
      displayFirstSlot: {
        type: [String, Boolean],
        default: true,
      },
      lookUpTableName: {
        type: String,
      },
      overridePageMode: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      readOnlyValue: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
    computed: {
      rules () {
        return (this.isRequired && (!this.plaintext && !this.pagePlaintext) ) ? "required" : "";
      },
      computedVal: {
          get () {
            return this.value;
          },
          set (val) {
            return val;
          },
      },
      classObject,
      refDataValue () {
        return this.getSelectedDataValue(
          this.options,
          this.computedVal,
          this.selectValue,
          this.selectText,
        );
      },
      divClass () {
        return this.multiple
          ? "multiSelect"
          : (this.disabled || this.arcDisabledObj) === true
            ? "disable"
            : "autofill";
      },
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
      //this.$store.commit("Common/SET_ADDRESS_MIXIN_COUNT", 0);
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: can you show the component code that uses dropdownComissionerValues (html)?

Comment: are you using any ui library like vuetify or bootstrap?

Comment: I added the cmponent code...We do use bootstrap (BootstrapVue to be exact). But we are not using Bootstrap components directly. Instead a separate team built a series of re-usable components with the BootstrapVue library to make our own custom library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom component has `selectValue` and `selectText` props, which allows setting the [`b-form-select`'s `value-field` and `text-field`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#comp-ref-b-form-select-props), respectively. You could set those to the desired values without having to remap your data:

```html
<WDropDown :options="dropdownCommissionerValues"
   selectText="CommissionerName"
   selectValue="CommissionerId"
/>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-butterfly-sb8du?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: Still getting the same output.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction in Codesandbox?

Comment: Well, I thought of that but I wouldn't be able to connect the API to it and it works with local data

Comment: @LOTUSMS are you sure you are modifying the code in the right place and the page is refreshing after changes?

Comment: @tony19 I'll try and put one together. But I know that if I put the data locally (mimicking the API response) it works fine cause that's how we did it while we were designing. We're in the phase of replacing the local data with API responses now

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to respond. I was checking with the dev team because this should work and they verified there was something wrong with the API itself. They fixed it and this code worked fine. Thanks @tony19

Comment: @LOTUSMS No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

While not familiar with boostrapVue you could add keys (`text` and `value`) either after api call or from the component and using a computed.

Something like:

```
this.dropdownCommissionerValues = response.data.Table.map(option=>{
  option.text=option.commissionerName
  option.value=option.commissionerValue
  delete option.commissionerName // optional .... clean up the object
  delete option.commissionerValue // optional .... clean up the object
  return option
})
```

Comment: dang it. This looks like it would work but it returned the same results. I was hopeful :(

Comment: @LOTUSMS when you use vue inspector did the object keys change? Where did u implement this, computed or after api?

Comment: The object keys remain the same

Comment: if the object keys remain the same then the data is being changed/sent from somewhere else